# process stop working while queue is not empty

Tags: python, queue, multiprocessing

I try to write a script in python to convert url into its corresponding ip. Since the url file is huge (nearly 10GB), so I'm trying to use multiprocessing lib.

I create one process to write output to file and a set of processes to convert url.

Here is my code:

```
import multiprocessing as mp
import socket
import time

num_processes = mp.cpu_count()
sentinel = None


def url2ip(inqueue, output):
    v_url = inqueue.get()
    print 'v_url  '+v_url

    try:
        v_ip = socket.gethostbyname(v_url)
        output_string = v_url+'|||'+v_ip+'\n'

    except:
        output_string = v_url+'|||-1'+'\n'
    print 'output_string   '+output_string
    output.put(output_string)
    print output.full()

def handle_output(output):
    f_ip = open("outputfile", "a") 
    while True:
        output_v = output.get()

        if output_v:
            print 'output_v   '+output_v
            f_ip.write(output_v)
        else:
            break    
    f_ip.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    output = mp.Queue()
    inqueue = mp.Queue()
    jobs = []
    proc = mp.Process(target=handle_output, args=(output, ))
    proc.start()

    print 'run in %d processes' % num_processes

    for i in range(num_processes):
        p = mp.Process(target=url2ip, args=(inqueue, output))
        jobs.append(p)
        p.start()


    for line in open('inputfile','r'):
        print 'ori    '+line.strip()
        inqueue.put(line.strip())

    for i in range(num_processes):
        # Send the sentinal to tell Simulation to end
        inqueue.put(sentinel)

    for p in jobs:
        p.join()

    output.put(None)
    proc.join()
```

However, it did not work. It did produce several outputs (4 out of 10 urls in the test file) but it just suddenly stops while queues are not empty (I did check queue.empty())

Could anyone suggest what's wrong?Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're workers exit after processing a single url each, they need to loop internally until they get the sentinel.  However, you should probably just look at [multiprocessing.pool](http://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#module-multiprocessing.pool) instead, as that does the bookkeeping for you.